# Having issues executing file as sudo or root

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, sudo

I have an Geant4 c++ executable on a x64 Ubuntu 18.04 PC which acts in a very strange way.

1.- If I try to run it as normal user:

`user@MyPC:~$ ./myExec`

It runs, but doesn't visualize as it should.

2.- If I run it with sudo:

```
user@MyPC:~$ sudo ./myExec
```

it doesn't run, throwing an fatal exception.

3.- If I change user to root and try to run it:

```
user@MyPC:~$ sudo su
```

```
root@MyPC:~# ./myExec
```

it doesn't run and throw the same fatal exception

4.- But, if I do:

```
user@MyPC:~$ sudo -s
```

```
root@MyPC:~# ./myExec
```

It runs perfectly

5.- If I try to do:

```
user@MyPC:~$ su root
```

I can't get loged in, since my sudo password doesn't work here.

So, my question is, how can I do for scripting the 4th (successful) case, in order to avoid the login in each time I want to run my executable or even be able to running from a click.

Comment: Sounds like your program is expecting something to be set up for it like environment variables. You might put in some debugging to see what statement is causing the problem. Then post that info here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide your distro name and its version.

Comment: Also show us the results of the commands, including the "fatal exception" message.